# Using Local Storage to cache Kendo datasource data

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a page that has many identical Kendo DropDownLists (MVC flavour).  I'd like to cache the dataset that will be used to populate the dropdownlists in ajax when the page is loaded, then bind the dropdownlists to this local data object as required.

At present I am doing the following to create a LocalStorage object at page load time:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/Job/GetEmployees",
        type: "get",
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                offlineStorage: "employeesStorage",
                data: data
                });
            dataSource.read();
            return false;
        },
        error: function (msg) {
          //  tostr.error("Error: " + msg.statusText);
        }
    });
```

This successfully creates a Local Storage object called employeesStorage with the correct data in.

Despite much googling I can't see how to utilise this data to populate my EditorTemplates - the closest I have got is:

```
@Modeltype models.employeesVM
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList _
    .Name("Salesman") _
        .DataValueField("employee_id") _
        .DataTextField("LastName") _
        .DataSource(Function(s) s.Read(Function(read) read.Action("GetEmployees", "Job"))) _
        .OptionLabel("Select Employee")
)
```

...which obviously populates the DDL off the controller when in fact I want to populate it from the local data.
How do I reconfigure the DDL to access the local storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - some help from Telerik support and I got the answer.

DropDownList doesn't support being able to populate itself from local storage, so it's simply a case of writing the necessary JS to populate it at render time:

```
   @Modeltype models.employeesVM
   @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList _
    .Name("Salesman") _
        .DataValueField("employee_id") _
        .DataTextField("Employee") _
    .OptionLabel("Select Employee"))

<script>
    var locate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("employeesStorage"));
    $("#Salesman").data("kendoDropDownList").setDataSource(locate);
</script>
```

Simples!